# Calculating force in different scenarios

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider below two scenarios in which there is a requirement to measure force:

1. Person(70kg) moving in a car(with velocity=50m/s), applies break, Airbag opens and person comes to rest in time=10s. What's the force applied by Airbag on person? Is the force applied by person on Airbag the same?

Ans:

```
  F =  ( m * (vfinal - vinitial) ) / t
    =  ( 75 * (0 - 50) ) / 10 
    =  -375N
```

2. A person throws a ball vertically upwards and it reaches peak height in 10s? what is the force applied by person on the ball?

Ans:

When the ball is in vertical motion,

```
 vfinal = vinitial + gt

 vinitial = 0 - (-9.8)*10
          = 98m/s  ====> [1]
```

While person swings the ball(m=0.1kg) for a period of 5secs, the ball will be initially at 0m/s and he gives it a final velocity of 98/ms(from [1]), hence the force applied by person on ball is

```
  F * dt = m * dv 
  F = 0.1 * (98 - 0)/5 = 1.96N  [ dt=5s, dv=98-0=98m/s ]
```

Now finally i have two questions:

1. Is force always measured by its effects, i.e Can force be measured if we don't know other variables as in above questions?
2. In the second question above, the person applies a force of 1.96N on the ball, so according to newton's 3rd law, the ball also has to apply the same force on the person. Is it because the force is less and person's mass is considerably large, person doesn't experience any acceleration?

Comment: Neither problem is done correctly.  In the first problem, there is a simple algebraic error, but, in the second problem, the issue is more fundamental.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Could you just throw a hint as to what is wrong in second problem? Is it question or solution?

Comment: It's the solution.  You did not use the correct SUVAT equation to determine the release velocity.  Your calculated release velocity is not correct.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Not ringing any bell! .. Would you just clear up the suspense?

Comment: $v_f^2-v_i^2=2ad$

Comment: @ChesterMiller, well choosing, h = (vinitial+vfinal)/2 * t, gives vinitial = 20m/s .. how to know which equation leads the correct release velocity?

Comment: Regarding 2.: Once the ball leaves the thrower’s hand, the only significant force acting on it is gravity. So to find the force applied by the hand requires some info about how long the hand is in contact with the ball. Given the max height and the time to reach it, you can calculate the initial y velocity. Using that and the time the hand is in contact with the ball and applying force, you can use the impulse momentum equation to find the force on the ball by the hand.

Comment: $v_i=\sqrt{2gd}$

Comment: @ChesterMiller I am kind of getting lost here .... All SUVAT equations are for constant acceleration right? Then why i should use only vi = sqrt(2gd) ... why can't i use other equations?

Comment: OK.  Try it with these equations:  $$gt=v_i$$ and $$d=v_it-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$.  Substitute t from the first equation into the second equation and see what you get.

Comment: @ChesterMiller the question which i formed with h=100m,t=10secs was not a valid combination .. i have edited the question with just only time as given variable

Comment: Well, of course, changing the problem statement so it is easier to solve always helps.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Sorry, i didn't modify the problem statement to make it easier ... let me ask you one final question: is there a possible valid initial velocity for an object, for it to reach a peak height of 100m in 10s?

Comment: No, unless you change g.  It will reach the maximum height in about 4.5 sec. if the maximum height is 100 m with g equal to 10 m/s^2.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the second problem-

Use the fact that $F_n=\frac{dP}{dt}$ or net force acting on a body is equal to the rate of the change of momentum of the body by Newton's second Law.

Answer (score 0):

Force (F) = dP/dt

Where:
F = Force applied on the body
dP = Change in momentum
dt = Change in time

In the previous scenario, the person's initial momentum (p_initial) was 3500 kg m/s, and they came to rest in 10 seconds.

First, let's calculate the change in momentum (ΔP):
Change in Momentum (ΔP) = p_final - p_initial
ΔP = 0 - 3500 kg m/s = -3500 kg m/s

Next, we'll divide the change in momentum by the change in time (10 seconds) to get the force applied by the airbag on the person:
Force (F) = ΔP / Δt
F = (-3500 kg m/s) / 10 s
F = -350 kg m/s²
F = -350 N

So, the force applied by the airbag on the person is -350 N, which means it acts in the opposite direction to the person's initial motion.

According to Newton's third law, the force applied by the person on the airbag will also be 350 N in the forward direction (opposite to their initial motion), as we discussed before.